# Graph gadget related to uniquely hamiltionian regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, hamiltonian-paths

A graph is uniquely hamiltonian if it has exactly one hamiltonian cycle.

According to a conjecture there are no $r$-regular uniquely hamiltonian
graphs for $r > 2$ and of special interest is the case $r=4$ ($r=3$ is solved).

The following graph gadget (if it exists) will give $4$-regular
uniquely hamiltonian graph:

$G$ is finite simple connected graph. Two vertices $u,v$ are of degree $3$ and
the rest vertices are of degree $4$. There is exactly one $u-v$ hamiltonian
path.

> Does such gadget exist?

Computer search didn't find any on up to 12 vertices.

The $4$-regular graph is two copies of $G$: $G_1$ and $G_2$ and
additional edges $u_1 u_2$ and $v_1 v_2$.

Comment: So the conjecture is that a 4-regular uniquely hamiltonian graph doesn't exist, and you are looking for a relatively easy construction which might hopefully yield a counterexample to that. Good luck...! BTW, finding a certain graph with exactly one u−v hamiltonian path should not be that much easier.

Comment: @Wolfgang No, I am not trying to do this. Nonexistence won't say anything about the conjecture. I believe such gadget doesn't exist.

Comment: OK I see. So your goal is rather to rule out a certain category of possible counterexamples, by showing that such a gadget doesn't exist.

Comment: Thomason's result says that there are always an even number of Hamiltonian paths in the similar scenario for r=3. Do you have any similar conjecture here, like the number of such paths is always divisible by 3?

Comment: I think you are really saying that if you can find a 4-regular graph with an edge lying in exactly one hamilton cycle, then you can build a 4-regular graph with one hamilton cycle in total. (It is not *exactly* this but very close.)

Comment: @domotorp There is no such conjecture about hamilton cycles through an edge in a 4-regular graph, as hamiltonian 4-regular graphs appear to have plenty of hamilton cycles, not just "a second", and the data for small graphs shows that pretty much anything can happen. In fact, if an edge lies in one hamilton cycle, then it seems to lie in at least six (and this only happens for $K_5$)

Comment: @GordonRoyle In the graph in the question if I add edge uv I will get 4-regular graph with uv on exactly one cycle. In the other direction, if uv is on exactly one cycle of 4-regular graph and it is deleted, the result will be G from the question unless I am mistaken. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @joro, yes. The only wrinkle is that uv may already be adjacent in the gadget, so the 4-regular graph may have just one doubled edge.

Comment: @GordonRoyle Indeed, thanks. So unlikely existence of a single gadget will give infinite family of counterexamples? Start from a small gadget, make a counterexample. In the unique HC of the counterexample delete an edge, finding bigger gadget. Repeat.