# Graph gadget related to uniquely hamiltionian regular graphs (question #2)

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, hamiltonian-paths

Related to uniquely hamiltionian graphs.

For natural numbers $a,b$ define $(a,b)$ gadget $G$:

$G$ is finite simple graph. Two vertices $u,v$ are of degree $b$
and the rest of the vertices are of degree $a$. There is exactly one
hamiltonian path $u-v$.

> Q1: Does $(3,2)$ gadget exist?
>
> Q2: Does $(4,2)$ gadget exist?

To get uniquely hamiltonian regular graph for Q2, take two copies
of the gadget $G_1$ and $G_2$. Merge $u_1,u_2$ and $v_1,v_2$.

Likely the answer to Q1 is positive since there are uniquely hamiltonian
graphs with minimum degree $3$ and maximum degree $4$, while the answer
to Q2 is likely negative since it is conjectured that there are no uniquely hamiltonian $4$-regular graphs.

Both gadgets are regular graph with two edges subdivided once.

Comment: Link to your previous question: "[Graph gadget related to uniquely hamiltionian regular graphs](http://mathoverflow.net/q/261273/6094)."

Answer (score 1):

Surely the answer to Q1 is negative. If you found such a graph, then by joining two copies together (joining $u$ in one copy to $u$ in the second, and the same for $v$), would this not give a 3-regular uniquely hamiltonian graph?

Comment: This appears to forbid unique hamiltonian **path** between a lot of vertices in cubic graphs. "Undoing" the subdivisions leaves a cubic graph and just removes the endpoints of the path. Problematic case is distance u-v = 2.